# python tkinter - how to set initial selection for radiobutton menu?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I am trying to implement a menu with tkinter which includes radiobuttons, but I am not able to select one of the options before clicking on one of them. When the GUI appears, no one of the radiobuttons is selected, instead I would like the second options selected. This is my code:

```
menubar = Menu(root)
# create a pulldown menu, and add it to the menu bar
settings = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
settings.add_command(label='some 1', command=some_1)
settings.add_command(label='some 2', command=some_2)
mDebug = Menu(settings, tearoff=0)
rvar = IntVar(root)   
rvar.set(1) 
mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='first', var = rvar, value = 0)
mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='second', var = rvar, value = 1) 
mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='third', var = rvar, value = 2)

settings.add_cascade(label='radio options', menu = mDebug)
settings.add_separator()
settings.add_command(label='quit', command=close)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=settings)
root.config(menu=menubar)
```

EDIT: this is a more complete version of the code:

```
from tkinter import *


def change(idx):
    print(idx)

def show_menu(root):
    menubar = Menu(root)
    settings = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    settings.add_command(label='some 1')
    settings.add_command(label='some 2')
    mDebug = Menu(settings, tearoff=0)
    rvar = IntVar(root)   
    rvar.set(1) 
    mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='first', var = rvar, value = 0, command=lambda idx=0: change(idx))
    mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='second', var = rvar, value = 1, command=lambda idx=1: change(idx)) 
    mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='third', var = rvar, value = 2, command=lambda idx=2: change(idx))

    settings.add_cascade(label='radio options', menu = mDebug)
    settings.add_separator()
    settings.add_command(label='quit')
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=settings)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

root = Tk() 

show_menu(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try setting the variable after creating the radiobuttons.

Comment: I tried also setting the variable after creating radiobuttons, but the result is the same

Comment: When I run your code as posted, with as few changes as possible to make it run, the radiobutton is properly initialized. Please create a _complete_ [mcve].

Comment: I added a reproducible example. I verified  that if I don't put the menu code in a separate function the code works. Why does not work in the second case I posted?

Comment: The fact that the code is in a function is an important detail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `rvar` is a local variable. When the function goes out of scope, python's garbage collection process will destroy the object.

You need to save a reference to the variable. For example, `self.rvar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# root = Tk()
# rvar = IntVar(root)
# rvar.set(1)

def change(idx):
    print(idx)

def show_menu(root):
    # global rvar
    try:
        show_menu.rvar
    except:
        show_menu.rvar = IntVar(root)
        show_menu.rvar.set(1)

    menubar = Menu(root)
    settings = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    settings.add_command(label='some 1')
    settings.add_command(label='some 2')
    mDebug = Menu(settings, tearoff=0)

    mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='first', var = show_menu.rvar, value = 0, command=lambda idx=0: change(idx))
    mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='second', var = show_menu.rvar, value = 1, command=lambda idx=1: change(idx))
    mDebug.add_radiobutton(label='third', var = show_menu.rvar, value = 2, command=lambda idx=2: change(idx))

    settings.add_cascade(label='radio options', menu = mDebug)
    settings.add_separator()
    settings.add_command(label='quit')
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=settings)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

root = Tk()
show_menu(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This works, at least in my Win10 py36 setup. Intrucing a global or using self.rvar in a class should also work as another commenter pointed out.